# Google Sheets: EXCLUDE hidden rows in query pulling unique data using indirect function

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, unique, google-query-language

I have an Apps Script pulling every tab name in my Google Sheet into a list. I'm then using a Query to pull all unique Names (from a Name column) from each of those tabs, with the Indirect function.

There are currently hidden rows in each of the tabs (there are 15 tabs total). The Query I have is currently pulling the Names in those hidden tabs.

How do I tell the Query to pull all unique data EXCEPT the hidden rows? Here is the existing Query formula I have which is including hidden row data (I'm only including 2 tabs of data here to shorten the formula for this example):

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({IF(B2="", {"","","",""}, INDIRECT(B2));IF(B3="", {"","","",""}, INDIRECT(B3))},"Select Col4 where Col4 is not null order by Col4 label Col4 'Names'",1))
```

The {"","","",""} is because I have INDIRECT formulas for future anticipated tabs which don't yet exist in the list of tabs, so I won't have to update the formula every time a new tab is added. For excluding the hidden data, I've looked into the SUBTOTAL formula but I'm having trouble applying it to this situation.

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10r6iGwDtjRqFTJ2E5z8S6SP1e9FnZPVpBx__uB9NmoM/edit?usp=sharing) a mock-up, smaller scale example of the sheet I'm working with. All of the names in the **Names** list on the *Tabs* tab that start with "Hidden" are in hidden rows on one of the tabs the query is pulling from. I want to exclude those Hidden names/rows from the query output.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe some few visuals (screenshots) or a sample sheet with sanitized data (FYI, sharing a sheet will render your email address visible to the public so proceed with caution on this option if this is uncomfortable for you)

Comment: @DiegoSanchez I've added a sample sheet. Thank you!

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to just have all that data on the same tab for all months and all years? and just add a column to keep track of the month/year?

Comment: @MattKing perhaps, but even if that was the case, how would I query unique names excluding hidden rows? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SUBTOTAL is the way but it does not work with arrayformula so you will need to drag it down into each row. see your sheet.

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY({
 IF(B2="",  {"","","","",""}, INDIRECT(B2));
 IF(B3="",  {"","","","",""}, INDIRECT(B3));
 IF(B42="", {"","","","",""}, INDIRECT(B4))},
 "Select Col4 
  where Col4 is not null 
    and Col5 = 1 
  order by Col4 
  label Col4 'Name'", 1))
```

also note the range change from A:D to A:E

[image]